# How to pause and continue CAKeyFrameAnimations in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cakeyframeanimation

Hi currently i am using a UIBezierpath for creating a path and tryng to  make a ball move along the path. Using CAKeyFrameAnimations i am able to move the ball along the path.
But how can i make the ball to move further along the path as along only when user taps a button. Something like when you press the button the ball should move from point 1 to point 2 on the bezier path.

So i thought i can play and pause the CAKeyFrameAnimations to give the same feel.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can dynamically recalculate your path on user's tap

Comment: Thanks for the response.Anyways found my answer here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html